# List of Objects: Efficiently getting a list of sum of ith attribute

Tags: python, performance, list, oop

Sorry if the title is confusing, I don't know how to really word this problem well.

I'm fairly new to programming outside of class projects/work, and I'm trying to develop good programming habits, and avoid loops where I can (i.e. staying away from inefficient code). A project I'm working on involves getting a list of sum of ith attribute from a list of objects, and I managed to do something with map comprehensions, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Say I'm working with a class `Foo`, with n attributes, `a1`, `a2`, ... , `an`, all integers, and a list `l` containing m of these objects.

For example, for `n = 3`, we could have something like:

```
l = [Foo(a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3), Foo(a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3), Foo(a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3)]
```

I want my result to look like:

```
sums = [3, 6, 9]
```

I did it this way:

```
sums = [sum([x.a1 for x in l]),
        sum([x.a2 for x in l]), 
        sum([x.a3 for x in l])]
```

Now the issue is, if `Foo` has a lot of attributes, then typing out each `x.an`could be unfeasible. The attributes don't necessarily have an integer attached to them as well, so they could be things like `Foo(these, are, some, attributes)`.

So, my question is, what is the "smart" way of solving this problem? Does it involve a use of a loop? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `inspect` module to extract a list of all arguments required to initialise a class instance.

Then iterate those arguments with a list comprehension:

```
import inspect

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, a3):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2
        self.a3 = a3
        pass

# get list of arguments, ignore the first which is self
args = inspect.getfullargspec(Foo.__init__).args[1:]

l = [Foo(a1=1, a2=2, a3=3), Foo(a1=1, a2=2, a3=3), Foo(a1=1, a2=2, a3=3)]

# use list comprehension to sum by attribute
sums = [sum([getattr(x, i) for x in l]) for i in args]

# [3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to use the *getattr* built-in function that returns the value of an attribute, using its name:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,a1,a2,a3):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2
        self.a3 = a3

l = [Foo(a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3), Foo(a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3), Foo(a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3)]

sums = [sum([getattr(x,'a{}'.format(i)) for x in l]) for i in range(1,4)]
```